# How to query info from distant database, PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have to code an application on my server that triggers emails based on info that come from a database hosted on another server and I don't know how to query that information. I'm using PHP/MySQL. I can't established a connection to this database like I do normally (when database is host on the same server that the application file), right?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong, there is no difference whether code and database are on the same or different servers. As long as the remote db server is configured to allow conections from foreign hosts that is... But that's a hosting issue not a programming one.

Comment: You're right, I just add my host in the **Remote Database Access Hosts** and voilà!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure why you wouldn't be able to. I've hosted databases on servers other than my hosting server before.

Try this

```
$my_db = mysql_connect('yourdb.com:3307', 'myuser', 'mypassword');
    if (!$my_db) die('This might be a problem: ' . mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

If mysql is on another machine , from mysql, you have to give permission for outsider.